# using daterangepicker.js how to select only day and month?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, daterangepicker

i have project in asp.net mvc and i m using daterangepicker.j for the datepicker. then how can i select only day and month in my text box.

my textbox is

```
<input type="text" id="yearEndDatePicker" placeholder="" data-bind="value: yearEnd" class="form-control">
```

my code is

```
$('#yearEndDatePicker').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            });
```

here i want format when select date is  "July 17"

Comment: Please provide a link to the plugin you are using ! And create a fiddle of your code !

Answer (score 3):

Didn't find anything about that, but I managed to find myself a solution, by using some custom settings.

```js
$('#date').daterangepicker({
  "singleDatePicker": true,
  "locale": {
    "format": "DD/MM",
  },
  startDate: '01/01',
  endDate: '31/12',
  minDate: '01/01',
  maxDate: '31/12',
  showDropdowns: true
}
);
```

```css
.yearselect{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" id='date'/>
```

It will let you pick date and month.

I couldn't remove the day-of-week / day-of-month relation. But with this setting, it'll always pick the current year's settings.

It's working fine. I had to use css to hide the year picker.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3xtze1k/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way :

```
$('#yearEndDatePicker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd MM'
    });
```

Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/9U8zT/2/

Comment: i m not using jquery.Ui.js, i m using daterangepicker.js, your code is right but not worked for daterangepicker, its worked for jquery ui